# lost css styling (using jquery) after visiting a new java server faces(jsf) page

Tags: jquery, css, jsf-2.2

I have a question about css styling using jquery in java server faces.
The followings are my codes.

In template.xhtml

```
<h:head>       
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>
    <h:outputScript name="./js/common.js"/>
    <title><ui:insert name="title"></ui:insert></title>
</h:head>

<ui:insert name="top" id="topui">
            <div id="topContent" >
                <h:form id="logo">

                    <span id="in" style="font-size: 33px; font-weight: bold;">Por 
                        <span style="color: rgb(255, 180, 0);">Permpol</span></span>
                    <div style="margin-left: 86px; color: gray; font-size: small;">
                        Organic Fertilizer
                    </div>
                </h:form>

                <h:form id="topnav">
                    <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="topli"><h:commandLink id="home" 
                             styleClass="topnavLinks" value="#{msg['home']}"  action="/index?faces-redirect=true" /></li>
                        <li class="topli"><h:commandLink styleClass="topnavLinks" value="#{msg['products']}" action="/products?faces-redirect=true"/></li>
                        <li class="topli"><h:commandLink styleClass="topnavLinks" value="#{msg['production']}" action="/production?faces-redirect=true" /></li>
                        <li class="topli" id="lang"><h:commandLink styleClass="aboutLink" value="#{msg['lang']}" title="click to change language"/>
                            <ul>
                                <li><h:commandLink id="en" styleClass="langsubmenu" actionListener="#{language.countryLocaleCodeChanged}" value="#{msg['eng']}&nbsp;●"/></li>
                                <li><h:commandLink id="th" styleClass="langsubmenu" actionListener="#{language.countryLocaleCodeChanged}" value="#{msg['thai']}&nbsp;●"/></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="topli" id="about"><h:commandLink styleClass="aboutLink" value="#{msg['about_us']} ▾"/>
                            <ul>
                                  <li><h:commandLink styleClass="submenu" value="#{msg['our_company']}  " action="/aboutus?faces-redirect=true" /></li>
                                <li><h:commandLink styleClass="submenu" value="#{msg['our_customers']}" action="/customers?faces-redirect=true"/></li>
                                <li><h:commandLink styleClass="submenu" value="#{msg['hallmark']}" action="/hallmark?faces-redirect=true"/></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </h:form>                

            </div>

        </ui:insert>
```

In common.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".topnavLinks").click(function() {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
        $(".topnavLinks").not(this).css("color", "white");
    });
});
```

When I select a menu item (of class "topnavLinks"), I want the selected menu item to be red while the others to be white.

From this code, when I click one menu item the selected item's font color is changed to red but when the jsf page loads successfully the css styling lost.

Anyone know what the problem is?
Unrelated point: To achieve this, is it necessary to use javascript(or jquery)? does jsf have a functionality to do so?

thanks

Comment: whatever you do in Javascript gets lost when you go to another page, Javascript changes the DOM of the current page. how to do it really depends on what you actually have to implement, you may store the info on the highlighted item in a cookie, session, db etc... then retrieve it when the page is loaded and do the javascript code to color the link

Comment: thanks for ur answer. Basically, I can create a managed bean of session scope to store current state right? is it possible to achieve this by non-javascript way(using only jsf components)?

Comment: maybe, I've never used the jsf taglib myself...